# How to create a shared folder on a remote Windows machine using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, shared-directory, directory-permissions

I want to manage shared folders on a remote machine from a C# application. Is there a way to do this using C#?

I know WMI can do remote management but I haven't found a way to manage file and folder sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Win32_Share WMI class can be used to manage shared resources, including folders.  The [MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) includes some sample code for creating a share (see the example by Radjin Sardjoe Missier on that page).